# Efficient way to filter non-empty directories in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have about 6 million jobs to run in a UNIX based system. For each one of them, I will have to create a directory in which there will be stored some results and log files. I have researched for fast ways in Python to:
1 - Create several subdirectories (one per simulation)
2 - Verify if each of these subdirectories contains at least one file, which may or may not have an extension

My best approach so far was to create directories with `os.mkdir` and filter non-empty directories with

```
for x in Path('.').iterdir():
    try:
        if os.listdir(x): # if list is not empty
            # do what I have to do
    except: pass
```

I have tried this in series, but it takes a massive amount of time. I wonder how I could run this task in parallel. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a multiprocessing pool. This task is mostly disk bound so I'm not sure how much of a boost it will give you. I opted not to use `pathlib` because passing `Path` objects is slightly heavier than just string to child processes.

```
import os
import multiprocessing as mp
import multiprocessing.pool

# examples for process and thread
USE_THREAD_POOL = True
if USE_THREAD_POOL:
    Pool = multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool
else:
    Pool = multiprocessing.Pool

def _directory_worker(dirpath):
    for fn in os.listdir(dirpath):
        if fn not in (".", ".."):
            # do your thing
            return

def directory_processor(dirpath):
    subdirs = [os.path.join(p) for p in os.listdir(dirpath)]
    # pick number of workers.... I am randomly saying half the cores
    worker_count = int(min(mp.cpu_count()/2, len(subdirs)))
    with Pool(worker_count) as pool:
        list(pool.imap_unordered(_directory_worker, subdirs, 
            chunksize=int(len(subdirs)/worker_count)))
```

Comment: It runs with no erros, however `_directory_worker()` doesn't seem to be called, because I can't print anything from inside of it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - yes, I think a thread pool would be good in this case. One would still have overlapping execution while workers wait on the disk. (to do that, just use `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` instead).

Comment: @CaioRocha - No good explanation here... I guess `min(mp.cpu_count()/2, len(subdirs))` could be zero if the subdirs list is wrong or if you are on a VM with a single core. Its worth printing its value.

Comment: @tdelaney I have already. Everything is ok but this. Do you have an idea of what it could be? Also, how should I use `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`? Could you post an answer with it, please? Thank you

Comment: @CaioRocha - my bad, I was still thinking python 2.x. The result of imap_unordered needs to be consumed before exiting the pool or the workers will be cancelled. I'll update to threads in a moment.

Comment: @tdelaney I was breaking down your code, to understand it better. Why did you write `os.path.join(p)` , `if p not in (".", "..")` and `if fn not in (".", "..")`. The results are the same if I take them out. Are they needed for some special condition?

Comment: @CaioRocha - they are part of directory listings on unix based systems ("." for current and ".." for parent) but checking just now I realized python os.listdir doesn't include them. So, they aren't needed. Thanks for pointing that out.